# LibGDX stretching 2d graphics

Tags: textures, sprites, libgdx, scale

I have a problem with stretching sprites in LibGDX.

I have one png file for the sky in the game (1 x 1000px) and I want to render it 1000 x 1000px

```
sprite.setSize(pixelWidth,pixelHeight);
```

I want to stretch [this 1px-wide sky image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whxWZ.png). It has little gradient from the top to the bottom, as you can see. I want to make it 1000px in width. But I get this strange result:

[image: GameScreen]

You can see that there is something like a horizontal gradient, even with lines, but there's no apparent reason why that's happening, since I'm scaling a 1px wide image!

The strange thing is that everything looks fine on other PCs and mobile phones - but I don't think that the problem is with my PC!?

I don't know what to try. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem you are experiencing is called banding. It may be your display settings. It may be the texture format of your image. Google "texture banding" as there are lots of resources to be found.

Comment: @PlayDeezGames: yasen is not worried about the banding. He's stretching his texture horizontally, so there should be no changes in the color horizontally. Did you read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, my ability to help you is limited. However, these are some ideas I can think of:

- There's another semitransparent texture on top of it, that is causing this problem. Try removing all other sprites, and if the problem is solved, then start adding sprites one by one to see which one is causing this problem.
- The texture coordinates are set to the corners, you're using bilinear filtering, and for some reason, the sampler is getting black pixels for out of range texture coordinates. To see if this is the  problem, make the texture 2 pixels wide or more. If the correct color covers a wider area, this is probably your problem.

  To fix this problem, you can do one or more of of:

  - Changing the texture U coordinates to 0.5 instead of 0 and 1
  - Explicity set the wrapping mode to clamp
  - Use nearest neighbor filtering
- The fragment shader is adding extraneous colors, probably due to an uninitialized uniform. Make sure you set values to all of your uniforms before you start drawing. In fact, this could actually explain why this only happens on your computer, which probably has shader debugging activated, and may set uninitialized uniforms to 0 (black).

The banding itself may be caused by the format of your framebuffer. When you created it, what pixel format did you set for it? RGBA4441 or similar could lead to banding like this.

Comment: Thanks man! If I had linear filtering. I tried to set it to nearest and it worked fine! It works also without any filtering :))

Comment: @yasen: Glad you got your problem fixed. However, there is no such thing as "no filtering". In computer graphics, filtering is the method used to determine the color of a pixel. The default is probably "nearest neighbor".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a gradient covering a rectangular area in libgdx, you can just use a `ShapeRenderer` and the method

```
shapeRenderer.fillRectangle(0,0,screenWidth, screenHeight, topColor, topColor, bottomColor,bottomColor);
```

for this.

It's a better solution as it's more portable and allows you to change the colors without making new art.

Comment: What if gradient is not uniform? E.g. spans across 3 or 4 different colors.

Comment: @KromStern: If you can provide functions for the blend factor of each color, you can create the gradient inside the fragment shader! That would be pretty awesome.

Comment: @Panda: Agreed, however A that is a different answer and B it's hard to tune shaders to artists Photoshop-made gradient ;)

Comment: @KromStern Yeah, I know I wasn't really answering the question, but I thought it would be useful in case he hadn't thought of doing it this way.